# Facebook - Get all mentions of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get a stream of posts that mention a specific page. So when someone create a post that mention @my_page, I want to pull that post.

I tried playing around with the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and [this part of doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions#pages). But can't seem to make it work.

So my question is:

1. Is that possible? If yes, how? I can't seem to find the right answer from Google
2. Do I need to get permission from user to allow access?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible with the API currently.

This is only possible with a select group of pages using the Mentions App.
http://www.facebook.com/mentions